# Excluding one element from the layout on the current child route in Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, layout, app-router

In Nextjs 13, using the app router, how can I exclude one element from the root layout from being rendered in a child route. I specifically would like to exclude the aside with the Feed component and keep the rest of the code:

```
// Exlude this:

<aside className={styles.feed}>
    <Feed />
</aside>
```

```
// layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
   
      <html lang="en" className={`${outfit.className} ${styles.html}`}>
        <body className={styles.body}>
          <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <aside className={styles.feed}>
              <Feed />
            </aside>
          <div className={styles.main}>
              <nav className={styles.nav}>
                <Navbar />
              </nav>
              <main className={styles.children}>{children}</main>
            </div>
          </div>

          <footer className={styles.footer}>
            <Footer />
          </footer>
        </body>
      </html>

  
  );
}
```

```
// page.tsx
const Listing = () => {

return (
 <section className={styles.gallery}>
   // code
 </section>   
  );
};

export default Listing;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two solutions

1. Make your feed component **'use client'** and add **usePathname** hook, and **do not render** at your route
2. If you want to make it **static** you can create two sub group folder with different layouts

**baseLayout.tsx**

```
export default function BaseLayout({
  children,
  isFeed
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  isFeed?: boolean
}) {
  return (
      <html lang="en" className={`${outfit.className} ${styles.html}`}>
        <body className={styles.body}>
          <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            {isFeed && (
              <aside className={styles.feed}>
                <Feed />
              </aside>
              )
            }
          <div className={styles.main}>
              <nav className={styles.nav}>
                <Navbar />
              </nav>
              <main className={styles.children}>{children}</main>
            </div>
          </div>

          <footer className={styles.footer}>
            <Footer />
          </footer>
        </body>
      </html>
  );
}
```

**app/(with-feed)/layout.tsx**

```
export default function WithFeedLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
   <BaseLayout isFeed>
     {children}
   </BaseLayout>
  );
}
```

**app/(no-feed)/layout.tsx**

```
export default function NoFeedLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
   <BaseLayout>
     {children}
   </BaseLayout>
  );
}
```